# Requests through another machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, xmlhttprequest, savon

Is it possible to make requests for example with Savon through something like ssh-tunnel. I can run this stuff from my stage server whose IP is whitelisted in the service I'm sending requests to. But of course I want to do the development on my computer :P so is there any option to do that? I've already tried savon's proxy:  option in many combinations such as

```
proxy: "http://name:password@my_stage_server.com"
```

etc. I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: you can do port-forwarding of the remote servers SOAP endpoint via ssh and point savon to that new location. savon only handles http connections, so you need to forward a port to connect to.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code becouse I quite to this kind of stuff? Thx

Comment: there is no code, type `man ssh`

Comment: I'm doing this ssh -D 8080 -Nf user@stage_server.com on my computer in console than I type the password. Then in console I see this row: ssh       5842          camol    3u  IPv4 0x6972dsdsdsdfff      0t0    TCP 192.xx.xx.xx:54529->198.xx.xx.xx:ssh (ESTABLISHED)  don't which info to use with savon and where

Comment: you should be able to access your soap endoint at the ip you forwarded to the port you forwarded from your browser. then just use that endpoint for savon!

Comment: i am using stuff like this to access a remote service on port 9200 `ssh -f user@server -L 9201:127.0.0.1:9200 -N`

Comment: I did ssh -L 5000:server_service.com:443 user@stage_server.com  and it worked partially becouse I can access now in web browser the service but the 'https' part in url is crossed and savon returns HTTPI::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Comment: Made it I've changed the ssl_version to TLSv1. Thx for guiding

Answer (score 1):

SSH tunnels are the way to go. They are easy to set up, use this in one terminal session:

```
ssh -L 8080:servicehost:80 myuser@stagingserver
```

Once established, leave it open. It'll open port 8080 on your localhost as a tunnel to the TCP service at host:443. Point savon to `http://localhost:8080/some/url/to/service` to access the service running on `http://servicehost/some/url/to/service`.

If you need this frequently, it's convenient to add it to your *ssh config file*, which is located at `~/.ssh/config`. It's a plain text file, the example above would look like this:

```
Host staging
  HostName hostname.domain
  LocalForward 8080 servicehost:80
  User myuser
```

With this configuration you can open the tunnel by simply issuing `ssh staging`. There are more options you could set, please refer to [the MAN page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config%205) for details.

### Hostname resolution

Keep in mind that the hostname `servicehost` must be resolvable *from your staging server*, not your development machine. You can use IP addresses, too.